# In prometheus operator how to shard using custom metrics

Tags: prometheus-operator

we are trying to do load balancing on prometheus operator as our clusters are big. Found this prometheus operator shard very useful but finding any clue on how to define the metrics per shard

in below manifest we can increase the shard value and that brings up multiple pods, but my question is can i configure shard to define what metrics will be scraped by which shard

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: prometheus
  name: prometheus
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  replicas: 2
  shards: 2
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      team: frontend
```